# Mage::getBaseUrl('media') returns url with http only in custom module

Tags: magento-1.7, url, module

I have developed a module to make a custom menu to show thumpnail images of sub categories when hover the main menu or category.

For that in the **Block** of my module, I return the src of each thumpnail images using the following.

```
return Mage::getBaseUrl('media').$thumnail
```

As it returns the url scheme as http always, checkout page is not completely secure. So I changed it to return secure url as below

```
return Mage::getBaseUrl('media',true).$thumnail
```

Then it returns always https in it's url scheme.

I want https, only for checkout page since it needs to be secure, and http for other pages.
How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Just change
 **Mage::getBaseUrl('media',true);**
to

**$this->getBaseMediaUrl();**

```
$this->getBaseMediaUrl().$thumnail;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It returns url scheme always as 'https'.

Comment: I want https, only for checkout page, not for other pages. Your solution returns https for all pages (As Mage::getBaseUrl('media',true) doing)

Answer (score 1):

Either not passing the second parameter or passing it as `null` should work here for you. When it builds the url if the secure parameter is null then if checks if you are currently on a secure page.

```
$secure = is_null($secure) ? $this->isCurrentlySecure() : (bool)$secure;
```

This then goes off and checks if you are requesting the page from http or https. Once this has been returned Magento then loads the url from the config from either the secure or unsecure node.

```
$url = $this->getConfig('web/' . ($secure ? 'secure' : 'unsecure') . '/base_url');
```

If you step through the functions you should be able to find the error but the function call should be `return Mage::getBaseUrl('media').$thumnail`